# Two Growths from One Tomato Seed

Tags: seedlings

I have planted tomato seeds and as far I remember I didn't put more than one seed in a planting hole of each seedling container. I was using tweezer to drop each seed into a hole. However, I am observing in 2 of 10 seedlings that I seeded two growths from one seed. Is it possible or I might incidentally dropped two seeds in a hole in those seedling containers?

Comment: I have seen multiple seedlings sprouting from Lemon seeds.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing is that the seeds were not properly separated when they were drying. Two seeds can thus become "glued" together, so that they appear to be one seed.

I would cut off the less vigorous of the two, as they are too close, and will fight with each other for nutrients, and neither will win. Do not try to pull it out, as that will disturb the roots of the one you want to keep.

We save seeds every year, and this is a recurrent problem! When planting, examine each seed to see if it has an indentation around the edge. If so, it is probably two seeds. Just use your fingernail to separate them. If it does not separate cleanly, it was probably a malformed seed. Throw it away!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple tomato plants can sometimes come from one seed. I've grown a lot of tomatoes, but I've never seen it happen for sure myself. I've heard of it happening.

They call these polyembryonic tomatoes.

Here's a link that talks about some polyembryonic tomatoes that were found: https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/abs/10.4141/cjps58-010